# How to do rails migrations on existing records (historical data)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a model (Model_A) with two columns (Column_A and Column_B)

My model has the following method in it, two generate value of column_B based on column_A

```
Class Model_A < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_column_B

  def set_column_B
      self.column_B = get_value_from_column_A
  end

  def get_value_from_column_A
    # manipulate data from A to get value
    column_A.join(,) 
  end

end
```

I know I have to create a new column_B as a first step in the migration, However how do I change all pre-existing records in the database to have the correct value in column_B?
Should I write a script or a Rake task to this or is there a way I can do it through migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Looping over all records is a bad idea if you have a lot of records in them. Let's say you have 2 million records It will take forever to update the column and then executing the callbacks and validations if you are going `ActiveRecord` way.

If you can do it with SQL itself you can update all records using SQL way

Something like this migration from Spree

```
class UpdateNameFieldsOnSpreeCreditCards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name.downcase.include? "mysql"
      execute "UPDATE spree_credit_cards SET name = CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"
    else
      execute "UPDATE spree_credit_cards SET name = first_name || ' ' || last_name"
    end
  end

  def down
    execute "UPDATE spree_credit_cards SET name = NULL"
  end
end
```

Comment: in this case, I am not using the method in the model to generate the value. This seems more like to add a default value?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in that method? If it is like concatenation, multiplication, addition or something which we can achieve using the SQL you can use raw update all

Comment: Is your columnA Array data type?

Comment: Column_A is of type text. I am using serialize to store a hash of the format, "sample": [
     {"name": "A",
      "value": ["string1", "string2"] 
     }
  ]. I am trying to parse this hash and return a string based on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the migration you can do the following:

```
 class AddColummBToModelA < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    unless column_exists? :budgets, :column_b
      add_column :budgets, :column_b ......
      ModelA.find_each {|x| x.save! }
    end

  end

  def down
   remove_column :budgets, :column_b if column_exists? :budgets, :column_b
  end
end
```

Comment: You might wanna change it to `ModelA.all.find_each {|x| x.save! }`

Comment: oh yes, that would be more efficient.